# FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: xxx not found when located in WEB-INF/libs/

Tags: java, maven, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a JSF 2.2 component that works fine when located in the WAR project.
So the class file get put into the folder WEB-INF/classes/com/test

But when the Class is packaged into a JAR file (from another Maven project) and is located in the folder WEB-INF/lib/example1.jar then I get the following error.

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: HtmlHelloWorld not found.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1933)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1168)
```

Can anyone shed some light on why I get this or how to fix it.

Here is my code, not that I think it has any effect on the problem.

```
@FacesComponent(value = "HtmlHelloWorld")
public class HtmlHelloWorld extends UIComponentBase {
    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeAll(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    }
}
```

I should also add I have a "faces-config.xml" located in the root of the JAR. This makes no difference though.

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">

  <application>
    <resource-bundle>
      <base-name>i18n</base-name>
      <var>bundle</var>
    </resource-bundle>
    <locale-config>
      <default-locale>en</default-locale>
      <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
      <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
      <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
  </application>

</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have my faces-config.xml located in the META-INF folder

```
Project
| src
| | main
|   | java
|     | com.test.TestFacesComponent
|   | resources
|     | META-INF
|       | faces-config.xml
```

references : [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnawo/index.html)
Extract....

The JavaServer Faces implementation finds the file or files by looking for the following:

A resource named /META-INF/faces-config.xml in any of the JAR files in the web application’s /WEB-INF/lib/ directory and in parent class loaders. If a resource with this name exists, it is loaded as a configuration resource. This method is practical for a packaged library containing some components and renderers.

A context initialization parameter, javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES, that specifies one or more (comma-delimited) paths to multiple configuration files for your web application. This method will most likely be used for enterprise-scale applications that delegate to separate groups the responsibility for maintaining the file for each portion of a big application.

A resource named faces-config.xml in the /WEB-INF/ directory of your application. This is the way most simple applications will make their configuration files available.